# Bootstrap modal doesnt work in cloud

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, azure, azure-web-app-service

I had implemented bootstrap modal in my project, coded in ASP.NET with MVC. I implemented bootstrap modal for few fields. The modals work well when I run the project on localhost. However, the modal doesn't load at all/closes immediately on pop up on the version that is hosted on azure. 
Not sure what am I missing here. Any suggestions, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all required CSS, JS files are available and if any errors appear in your browser Console tool. And if possible, please share your code that can help reproduce the problem.

Besides, I'm using Bootstrap Modal Plugin in my web app, which works fine both on local and Azure, you can refer to the sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="openmodal()">Open Modal Via JavaScript</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function openmodal() {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    }
</script>
```

[image]

As I did in above code, you can try to manually trigger the modal via JavaScript and check if it works fine on your web app.

Comment: Why would you link to w3schools, when Bootstrap has it's own site? http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been trying to open modal without javascript function. Shouldn't that still be working on the cloud version? Also, I am trying to implement modal inside different tabs in mvc. The modal doesnt load if I write teh modal-related HTML code outside the _Layout.cshtml file. Since my code is scattered among the various parts of cshtm, i'm unable to post my code here as it's too large.

Comment: ``i'm unable to post my code here as it's too large`` If possible, you can upload your code to GitHub and share the link.